# Cannot save properties of may-to-many relationship model(mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, many-to-many, mongoose-schema

I`m creating a bookstore and I have 3 models: Book, Author and Genre.
Books stores an array of authors ids and the array of genres ids. Author stores the array of books ids. Genre too has the array of books ids.

```
    BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    authors: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Author"
        }
    ],
    image: String,
    description: String,
    price: Number,
    genres: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Genre"
        }
    ],
});


AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    books: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Book"
        }
    ],
});

GenreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    books: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Book"
        }
    ],
});
```

Then I have a data array that stores information about the book we need to create like this

```
{
        title: "The Monster at the End of This Book",
        authors: ["Jon Stone"],
        img: "https://images-na.jpg",
        price: "0.35",
        description: "Carve out family time for ...",
        genres: ["Children's Humour (Books)"]
    },
```

I`m trying to add authors, genres and books. After that I want to associate authors with books

```
Book.deleteMany({}, () => {
    insertBooks().then(insertGenres).then(insertAuthors).then(connectBooksToAuthors);
}).then(function () {
    connectBooksToGenres();
})

async function insertAuthors() {
    let authorsArr = [];
    data.forEach(dataPiece => {
        dataPiece.authors.forEach(author => {
            if (authorsArr.indexOf(author) === -1) {
                authorsArr.push(author)
            }
        })
    })
    authorsArr.forEach(author => {
        Author.findOne({name: author}, (err, a) => {
            if (!a) {
                Author.create({name: author});
            }
        })
    })
}

async function insertGenres() {
    let genresArr = [];
    data.forEach(dataPiece => {
        dataPiece.genres.forEach(genre => {
            if (genresArr.indexOf(genre) === -1) {
                genresArr.push(genre);
            }
        })
    })
    genresArr.forEach(genre => {
        Genre.findOne({name: genre}, (err, g) => {
            if (!g) {
                Genre.create({name: genre});
            }
        })
    })
}

async function insertBooks() {
    data.forEach((dataPiece) => {
        let obj = {
            "title": `${dataPiece.title}`,
            'description': `${dataPiece.description}`,
            "price": `${dataPiece.price}`,
        };
        Book.create(obj);
    })
}

async function connectBooksToAuthors() {
    data.forEach(dataPiece => {
        Book.findOne({"title": `${dataPiece.title}`}, (err, book) => {
            let authorsArr = [];
            dataPiece.authors.forEach(authorsName => {
                Author.findOne({name: authorsName}, (err, author) => {
                    author.books.push(book);
                    author.save();
                    authorsArr.push(author);
                     if (authorsArr.length === dataPiece.authors.length) {
                         book.authors = [...authorsArr];
                         book.save();
                     }
                });

            });
        })
    })
}

async function connectBooksToGenres() {
    data.forEach(dataPiece => {
        Book.findOne({"title": `${dataPiece.title}`}, (err, book) => {
            let genresArr = [];
            dataPiece.genres.forEach(genreName => {
                Genre.findOne({name: genreName}, (err, genre) => {
                    genre.books.push(book);
                    genre.save();
                    genresArr.push(genre);
                    if (genresArr.length === dataPiece.genres.length) {
                        book.genres = [...genresArr];
                        book.save();
                    }
                });

            });
        })
    })
}
```

When I run the code I get this exception:
(node:29028) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: VersionError: No matching document found for id "5fa1dbbb969d727164f1f59e" version 0 modifiedPaths "genres"
at generateVersionError (C:\Users\sasha\Desktop\Bookstore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:421:10)
at model.Model.save (C:\Users\sasha\Desktop\Bookstore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:478:28)
at C:\Users\sasha\Desktop\Bookstore\seed.js:234:34
at C:\Users\sasha\Desktop\Bookstore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4844:16
at C:\Users\sasha\Desktop\Bookstore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4844:16
at C:\Users\sasha\Desktop\Bookstore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
at C:\Users\sasha\Desktop\Bookstore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4867:21
at C:\Users\sasha\Desktop\Bookstore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4420:11
at C:\Users\sasha\Desktop\Bookstore\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:66:3)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:434:9)

In the database books `arrays with authors are filed. Ganres arrays are not The problem might be in book.save() calls from connectBooksToAuthors and connectBooksToGenres but I don`t really know how to fix it

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You haven't really told us what your specific problem is.

Comment: Sorry, added at the end of the question

Comment: Your code uses `.then()` callbacks, but on first glance, your functions aren't using `await` anywhere. It probably means that your functions are relying on objects that aren't created yet.